# How to run applescript at scheduled time

Tags: automation, applescript

How can I run my apple script at a scheduled time. I want it to run every 45 minutes, but I do not know how to do this. I saved my apple script as an application. What should I do next?

Thanks

(Currently, I am using the `on idle` function, but is there a better way to do so?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways:

- Create a recurring event in Calendar.app which triggers the script
- Create a launchd agent in ~/Library/LaunchAgents with the key `StartInterval` value `2700`

Both ways can handle standard compiled scripts (.scpt or .scptd)

Answer (score 2):

I would set up `crontab` to run the script using `osascript` command. See https://betterprogramming.pub/https-medium-com-ratik96-scheduling-jobs-with-crontab-on-macos-add5a8b26c30 for example.

Because `crontab` sets time in hours and minutes, I would set the Apple Script to run every 15 minutes and check in the first lines if it's the right time to start the body of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this launchd tutorial](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24748) for running an AppleScript on a schedule.